# Identify change in value over time with group_by, R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a dummy based on if a variable within a group changes over time.

Here is my data:

```
Winner <- c("X", "Y", "Z", "Y", "Y", "Z")
year<-c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020")
CPV <- c(0, 1, 1, 1,0,1)
test <- data.frame(Winner, year, CPV)
```

```
Winner    year     CPV
X         2019      0
Y         2019      1         
Z         2019      1
Y         2019      1
Y         2020      0
Z         2020      1
```

So, I would like to track if `CPV` changes between 2019 and 2020 for each `Winner`. If there is a change, a dummy variable `change` is 1, 0 if it remains the same, and NA if there are no observations for the next year.

Desired output:

```
Winner    year     CPV   change
X         2019      0       NA
Y         2019      1       1         
Z         2019      1       0
Y         2019      1       1
Y         2020      0       1
Z         2020      1       0
```

I've tried this code:

```
CPV_change<-test %>%
  group_by(Winner, year) %>%
  mutate(change = case_when(CPV != lag(CPV) ~ TRUE,TRUE ~ FALSE))
```

However, the use of the lag here isn't producing the output grouped by the variables `Winner`, `year`, but appears to be basing the change on sequential ordering.

Output that the above code produces:

```
Winner    year     CPV      change
X         2019      0       FALSE
Y         2019      1       TRUE         
Z         2019      1       TRUE
Y         2019      1       TRUE
Y         2020      0       FALSE
Z         2020      1       FALSE
```

Any ideas about how I can do this? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why is `Y` for 2020 1 (5th row) in desired output ?

Comment: I'd like the desired output to mark if a change occurred at all for the Winner. So, since Y had a change (row 4 to row 5), the variable is marked as 1 for all instances of Y.

Comment: But when two rows for same winner during the year happens to be different, how will you proceed?  See there are two rows for Y in 2019

Comment: Or say what if say CPV in row 4 is 0 & row 6 is not there!

Comment: This is a good point. In my case I am not concerned with changes during the same year, but I appreciate you pointing this out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `case_when` :

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  arrange(Winner, year) %>%
  group_by(Winner) %>%
                            #No next year data
  mutate(change = case_when(n_distinct(year) == 1 ~ NA_real_, 
                            # If there is a change
                            any(diff(CPV) != 0) ~ 1, 
                            #No change
                            TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
   ungroup

 Winner year    CPV change
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 X      2019      0     NA
2 Y      2019      1      1
3 Y      2019      1      1
4 Y      2020      0      1
5 Z      2019      1      0
6 Z      2020      1      0
```

In `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[order(Winner, year), change := fcase(uniqueN(year) == 1, NA_real_,
                              any(diff(CPV) != 0), 1,
                              default = 0), Winner]
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I really struggled with doing this with ```case_when```, thank you~

Comment: Is there by chance a way to do this with big datasets? I have a dataset with 5 million observations, and this command has been crashing my R

Comment: `data.table` package might help, I edited the answer to include that